# How to connect exhaust fan switch to bathroom light switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, toilet, light, exhaust-fan

[image]
How to connect the exhaust fan switch to the light switch? I have opened the exhaust fan before, there are:

- 2 permanent live wires
- 1 blue wire connected to neutral
- 1 black wire connected to switched live​

As I am new to electrical, can anyone advise me what can I do to connect the wires?
The ideal outcome is when I turn on the light switch, the fan gets turned on together.
Where can I start from?

I am happy to send more photos for confirmations.

Thanks

Comment: Safety first, wile pluming will not kill you, Electricity can. Get a phase tester tool. It look like a pen, and it can be used to determine if there is lethal power present before starting the work.

Comment: Presumably you can not access the wire cables from the attic.  If you can let's talk.

Comment: What is above the ceiling?  Is it hollow (eg wood frame) or solid (eg concrete)?  Are you willing to break and repair the ceiling a little? Are the fan and light on the same circuit breaker and are they on a common fused spur?